# how to keep line break in text extracted from textarea using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a review input box using `<input type='textarea'>` and a section to show the reviews.
I had created a javascript program to take the text typed in the Textarea when clicked on submit and show that in the review section. The problem is that the text is being shown without the line break which was given in textarea. I want to show the text exactly the same way along with line breaks in the review section.
Javascript code is:

```
function addcommentsFunc() {
let textarea=document.querySelector(".comment-textarea");
let commenttext = textarea.value;
commenttext= commenttext.replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n");
console.log(commenttext);
document.querySelector("#outer_review_container").innerHTML = `
  <div class="comments-container">
    <h3>Reviews</h3>
    <div class="posted-comments-container">
      <ul class="show-comments">
        <li><h4>By ${user_name}</h4>
            <div class="review-para-container">
              <p class="review-para" onclick="paraclamp(this)">${commenttext}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>`;
```

}

the input is like this:

[Screeshot of text entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VBy.png)

One thing is that if I use `console.log(commenttext);`
I get output with line break
But not same with html.
html output is like this:

I also tried `commenttext.replace("\r\n", "<br>")` but it was showing 
 as it is on web page.

[screenshot of text rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QSZk.png)

I hope I described my problem clearly. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try to use `replace('\n', '<br>')` instead of `'\n\r'`

Comment: I tried this but the <br> tag is getting printed as it is along with paragraph text. it is not giving a line break. isn't it that the template literal is (` `) treating <br> as plain text?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `innerText`, it seems that it retains whitespace.

```js
p.innerText = "Hello I have\nsome new\nlines\n\n:D";
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
```

I would suggest avoiding `innerHTML`, ***especially*** when you are using it to inject user-provided content.